# matlab sphere definition as txt file

Tags: matlab, geometry, matlab-figure

I wrote a matlab file to generate a 3D sphere:

```
obstacle.origin_x=1.6;
obstacle.origin_y=0.8;
obstacle.origin_z=0.2;
obstacle.radius_obs=0.2;
save('obstacle.mat', 'obstacle');
```

I found a code which is appropriate for my problem but the obstacle definition is in .txt format

how can I define it as a .txt format?

For instance in the code that I found, a rectangular prism is defined as:

```
-0.5000         0    0.5000
0.1500         0    0.5000
0.1500         0   -0.5000
-0.5000         0   -0.5000

0.3500         0    0.5000
0.5000         0    0.5000
0.5000         0   -0.5000
0.3500         0   -0.5000

0.1500         0    0.5000
0.3500         0    0.5000
0.3500         0    0.3500
0.1500         0    0.3500

0.1500         0    0.1500
0.3500         0    0.1500
0.3500         0   -0.5000
0.1500         0   -0.5000
```

Comment: See [`fprintf()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) or one of its wrappers, like [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question... this is what I interpret:

you want to define the raster points of a sphere (= "obstacle") in a txt-file, instead of defining only the parameters of the sphere within a struct?

If this is true you at first have to calculate all the raster points of the sphere by yourself, and then you can print them to a text file, e.g. using fprintf.

I've written a short function which draws a sphere:

```
function drawsphere()

bound_horz = 360*pi/180;    % horizontal angle boundaries
bound_vert = 90*pi/180;     % vertical angle boundaries
stepsize = 30;              % discretization step size
r = 400;                    % radius of sphere

% define angle raster points
[theta,phi] = meshgrid(linspace(-bound_horz,bound_horz,stepsize),linspace(-bound_vert,bound_vert,stepsize));
% convert them to Cartesian coordinates
x = r.*cos(theta).*cos(phi);
y = r.*sin(theta).*cos(phi);
z = r.*sin(phi);

C1 = zeros(size(x));
C2 = zeros(size(x));
C3 = ones(size(x));
col = cat(3,C1,C2,C3);

% draw the sphere
fig333=figure(333);clf
cameratoolbar(fig333,'Show')
cameratoolbar(fig333,'SetMode','orbit')
axis vis3d
surf(x,y,z,col);
```

Add fprintf-calls in the end to write x/y/z to a .txt file.